# ASP.Net Identity - External logins without any UI from Web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, external, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

Note: Just learning Identity so please bear with me. We are developing a Web API for use by apps that we build and apps built by our clients. I have the local engine working the way I want so that any "client" app could use our API to login in.

What I cannot seem to get to work is external login providers without being presented with a login page. Is it possible to converse with them in API only mode or is this type of setup out of the question? What I don't want our client's apps to have to do is know how to manage the logins to use our API.

I know this may be similar to a few other questions out there but I do not see one with our particular need.

Thanks,
Paul Speranza

Answer (score 0):

If your api needs to have authentication in place then you would need some kind of registering done by the consumers of your api. But you could provide seamless ways to integrate login by not providing any additional form requirements from the client application. Popular login methods today are using social networks. Web api does support out of the box support for integrating with the social networks.

You can find a sample for using facebook authentication [here](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/asp-dot-net-web-api-and-external-login-authenticating-with-social-networks/)